# version node not found for symbol

Tags: linker, gstreamer, yocto, libc

I've build a shared library on my desktop that uses statically linked gstreamer and gstreamer plugins (base, good, rtsp-server).

Now I'm trying to compile the library using yocto but its giving me a linker error:

```
version node not found for symbol _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.17
failed to set dynamic section sizes: Bad value
```

The solutions I found on stack overflow did not seem to help me.

- use compiler with `--disable-symvers`
- link libc libs in different orders (`-ldl -lm -lc -lpthread -ltinfo -lrt`)
- link libc libs statically/shared

What I find particularly odd is that the linker is looking for `GLIBC_2.17` while yocto uses `2.27` and my system is using `2.24`. I don't know if this matters or if it is normal (the function did not change since 2.17?).

`NM -C` shows the symbol in `libc.a`:

```
nm -C recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a | grep IO_do_write                                                                                             
                 U _IO_do_write
                 U _IO_do_write
0000000000001ba8 W _IO_do_write
```

So I would thinks that lib is linked incorrectly?

The linker command is a long one because of all the shared libs so I shortend it a bit (removed boost and custom libs):

```
aarch64-poky-linux-g++ -fPIC --sysroot=recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=recipe-root/git-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=recipe-sysroot-native=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   --sysroot=recipe-sysroot  -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wsuggest-override -Wswitch-default -Wduplicated-cond -Wshadow -Werror -ftemplate-depth=1024  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -lc -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -pthread -ldl -shared -Wl,-soname,rtsp_streamer.so -o rtsp_streamer.so ... custom static libs .and boost static libs ... -lpthread recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtsp.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtp.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtpmanager.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcoreelements.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstadder.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstapp.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudioconvert.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudiorate.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudioresample.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudiotestsrc.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstgio.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstpango.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgsttypefindfunctions.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoconvert.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideorate.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoscale.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideotestsrc.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvolume.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideofilter.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libBrokenLocale_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libanl.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libanl_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libatomic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libatomic_ops.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libatomic_ops_gpl.a ... more boost static libs ... recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libc_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcidn_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypt.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypt_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypto.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libdl.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libdl_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libg.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgomp.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstallocators-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstbase-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstcheck-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstcontroller-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstfft-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstpbutils-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstriff-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstrtp-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstrtsp-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstrtspserver-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstapp-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstnet-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstsdp-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgsttag-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libhistory.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libitm.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/liblicensing.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libm.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libm_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libmcheck.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libncurses++.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libncurses++w.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnsl.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnsl_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_compat_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_db_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_dns_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_files_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_hesiod_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_nis_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libnss_nisplus_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libprotobuf.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libprotoc.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libreadline.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libresolv.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libresolv_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/librpcsvc.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/librt.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/librt_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libssl.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libssp.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libssp_nonshared.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libstdc++.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libstdc++fs.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libsupc++.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libthread_db_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libutil.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libutil_pic.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libz.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/librt.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libm.a recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a
```

Does anybody know what is wrong? If more info is needed please ask. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong. The shared library is build using a CMAKE project and our own written `FindGSTREAMER.cmake`. To find gstreamer, among other things, a glob is used to find all the static libs. Because on my desktop I have gstreamer installed in its seperate location this works. With Yocto however this causes every static lib in the `recipe-sysroot/usr/lib` directory to be linked. Including every libc library (`.a`, `_pic.a` and `.so`). Apparently this causes the linker unable to resolve the symbols.

Correctly filtering the libraries needed by gstreamer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know what is wrong?

I suspect that you are not linking against GLIBC-2.27 from Yocto, but against some other GLIBC, though it is hard to see how that could happen.

Your first step should be to find out *which* `libc.so.6` is actually being used. You can do so by adding `-Wl,-t` flag to your link line. Also add `-Wl,-y,_IO_do_write` while you are at it.

After you know which `libc.so.6` is being used, run `readelf -Ws /path/to/libc.so.6 | grep _IO_do_write` to see what (if any) versioned symbols are defined in it.

> I don't know if this matters or if it is normal (the function did not change since 2.17)?

Yes: that is normal -- the function didn't change its ABI since GLIBC-2.17, so that's the version that is attached to it.

Comment: `-Wl, -t` shows: `/lib/libc.so.6 (recipe-sysroot/lib/libc.so.6)`
So that should be ok, `readelf` shows the symbol correctly:
`1334: 000000000006e610    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.17` 
`7374: 000000000006e610    56 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 __GI__IO_do_write`
`9010: 000000000006e610    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.17`

However I see it links to both `libc.so` and `libc.a` could that be a problem?